# pd.groupby on another groupby, transposing results of pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Another rather complicated question I'm stuck at regarding Pandas and its groupby and cut function. Situation is as follows, let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
import Pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data)

   A  B  C       ipv4
0  1  3  3    0.0.0.0
1  2  2  1  140.0.0.0
2  3  1  3  230.0.0.0
3  1  1  2  140.0.0.0
4  3  1  2        NaN
```

At this point, I have to add that the actual DataFrames I'm working with here can contain millions(!) of rows, so performance is something I have to keep in mind here.
I've made a function that gives me the power set of A, B and C, so `pset = [(A), (B), (C), (A,B), ... ]` without the empty one, you get the idea. I'm now grouping by each of these combinations in a loop and I'm creating a `count_df` for each one like this:

```py
for combination in pset:
    df.groupby(list(combination))
    count_df = df.size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
    print(count_df)

   A  count
0  1      2
1  2      1
2  3      2
...
   A  B  count
0  1  1      1
1  1  3      1
2  2  2      1
3  3  1      2
...
```

We're coming closer to my problem: I need to add some very very basic information about [IP classes](https://networkustad.com/2019/08/27/classful-network-addressing/) to each row of the `count_df` with their respective A-B-C combination (you can scroll down in the provided link to *High Order Bit (HOB)* and look at the table to get a quick idea of what I'm trying to do here). I've added another row to my `df` for this containing the first octet of each rows ipv4 and used Pandas' cut to get the counts for each interval quite fast:

```py
# I use 256 as value for any row that has "NaN" instead of a real address
df["ipv4"].replace(to_replace="NaN", value="256.0.0.0", inplace=True)
df["first_octet"] = df["ipv4"].apply(lambda x: int(x.partition(".")[0]))
df["cut_group"] = pd.cut(data["first_octet"], [0, 127, 191, 223, 239, 255, 256])

print(df)
   A  B  C       ipv4  first_octet       cut_group
0  1  3  3    0.0.0.0            0      (0, 127.0]
1  2  2  1  140.0.0.0          140  (127.0, 191.0]
2  3  1  3  230.0.0.0          230  (223.0, 239.0]
3  1  1  2  140.0.0.0          140  (127.0, 191.0]
4  3  1  2  256.0.0.0          256  (255.0, 256.0]

for combination in pset:
    df.groupby(list(combination) + ["cut_group"])
    count_df = df.size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
    print(count_df)

    A   cut_group  count
0   1    (0, 127]      1
1   1  (127, 191]      1
2   1  (191, 223]      0
3   1  (223, 239]      0
4   1  (239, 255]      0
5   1  (255, 256]      0
6   2    (0, 127]      0
7   2  (127, 191]      1
8   2  (191, 223]      0
9   2  (223, 239]      0
10  2  (239, 255]      0
11  2  (255, 256]      0
12  3    (0, 127]      0
13  3  (127, 191]      0
14  3  (191, 223]      0
15  3  (223, 239]      1
16  3  (239, 255]      0
17  3  (255, 256]      1
...
    A  B   cut_group  count
0   1  1    (0, 127]      0
1   1  1  (127, 191]      1
2   1  1  (191, 223]      0
3   1  1  (223, 239]      0
4   1  1  (239, 255]      0
5   1  1  (255, 256]      0
6   1  2    (0, 127]      0
7   1  2  (127, 191]      0
8   1  2  (191, 223]      0
9   1  2  (223, 239]      0
10  1  2  (239, 255]      0
11  1  2  (255, 256]      0
12  1  3    (0, 127]      1
13  1  3  (127, 191]      0
14  1  3  (191, 223]      0
15  1  3  (223, 239]      0
16  1  3  (239, 255]      0
17  1  3  (255, 256]      0
18  2  1    (0, 127]      0
19  2  1  (127, 191]      0
20  2  1  (191, 223]      0
21  2  1  (223, 239]      0
22  2  1  (239, 255]      0
23  2  1  (255, 256]      0
24  2  2    (0, 127]      0
25  2  2  (127, 191]      1
26  2  2  (191, 223]      0
27  2  2  (223, 239]      0
28  2  2  (239, 255]      0
29  2  2  (255, 256]      0
30  2  3    (0, 127]      0
31  2  3  (127, 191]      0
32  2  3  (191, 223]      0
33  2  3  (223, 239]      0
34  2  3  (239, 255]      0
35  2  3  (255, 256]      0
36  3  1    (0, 127]      0
37  3  1  (127, 191]      0
38  3  1  (191, 223]      0
39  3  1  (223, 239]      1
40  3  1  (239, 255]      0
41  3  1  (255, 256]      1
42  3  2    (0, 127]      0
43  3  2  (127, 191]      0
44  3  2  (191, 223]      0
45  3  2  (223, 239]      0
46  3  2  (239, 255]      0
47  3  2  (255, 256]      0
48  3  3    (0, 127]      0
49  3  3  (127, 191]      0
50  3  3  (191, 223]      0
51  3  3  (223, 239]      0
52  3  3  (239, 255]      0
53  3  3  (255, 256]      0
...
```

Ok, so the next step here is now missing for me. What I need is an output that looks like this for each combination of the pset:

```py
for combination in pset:
    <???>
    print(count_df)

   A  count  (0, 127]  (127, 191]  (191, 223]  (223, 239]  (239, 255]  (255, 256]
0  1      2         1           1           0           0           0           0
1  2      1         0           1           0           0           0           0
2  3      1         0           0           0           1           0           1
...
   A  B  count  (0, 127]  (127, 191]  (191, 223]  (223, 239]  (239, 255]  (255, 256]
0  1  1      1         0           1           0           0           0           0
1  1  2      0         0           0           0           0           0           0
2  1  3      1         1           0           0           0           0           0
3  2  1      0         0           0           0           0           0           0
4  2  2      1         0           1           0           0           0           0
5  2  3      0         0           0           0           0           0           0
6  3  1      2         0           0           0           1           0           1
7  3  2      0         0           0           0           0           0           0
8  3  3      0         0           0           0           0           0           0
...
```

I'm not sure how to get to that. The columns of `count_df` could also be `A-B-C  count  classA  classB  classC  classD  classE  classNaN` for clarification. The `count` column needs to indicate the count of how many underlying rows had the individual combination of A-B-C like I would get calling `df.groupby(list(combination)).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})`, the interval columns need to indicate the count of how many underlying rows were counted for the individual class of the individual combination  of A-B-C. You can sum up the problem to something like having a groupby with `groupby1 = df.groupby(list(combination) + ["cut_group"])` and after that another groupby on that one like `groupby2 = groupby1.groupby(list(combination))` and adding the class count information from `groupby1` transposed to rows. These last lines here are nonesense code, just to clarify what I mean.

I'm open to any suggestion regarding filling out the mentioned 'gap' in my code, aswell as any suggestion to maybe do something different here using other functions of Pandas which I don't know of yet. As always, I'm happy to learn different ways of using Pandas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pd.cut` has a small error: it ignores rows whose first octet is 0, since it does not include the lower edge by default. Start your bins at -1 instead.

```
df["first_octet"] = df["ipv4"].str.split('.', expand=True)[0].fillna(256).astype('int')

# Pivoting as CategoricalDType takes forever. I think this is a bug in pandas.
# Converting to string to make pivot_table faster
df["cut_group"] = pd.cut(df["first_octet"], [-1, 127, 191, 223, 239, 255, 256]).astype('str')
```

First, run a pivot for all three columns (A, B, C),

```
tmp = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A','B','C'], columns='cut_group', values='ipv4',
                     aggfunc='count', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
tmp['count'] = tmp.sum(axis=1)
```

Then you can groupby and sum any combinations of the 3:

```
from itertools import combinations
cols = list('ABC')

pset = []
for size in [1,2,3]:
    pset += [list(c) for c in combinations(cols, size)]
# pset = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]

result = [tmp.groupby(p).sum() for p in pset]
```

The execution time depends on the variability in A, B and C. It takes longer when there are more distinct values. For my random dataset (A, B, C being random 1-1000, 5M rows), it took about 40 seconds.

Comment: I finally went with your suggestion. First of all, thanks for finding the error with pd.cut :) working with pd.pivot_table is an awesome idea, I think I'll rework some of my code to use these tables right away from the start, so you've helped me even more than you might know! That really increased overall performance of my whole project, great!

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is to `join` a [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) of the column cut_group and then use `sum` in the `groupby`, something like:

```
# get dummies
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["cut_group"])
df_ = df.join(dummies) #you can reassign to df if you want

for combination in pset:
    gr = df_.groupby(list(combination)) #change to df if you reassign the join to df before
    count_df = (gr.size().to_frame('count')
                  .join(gr[dummies.columns].sum())
               )
    print(count_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just learned about pd.get_dummies because of that. I'll probably use this function later in another context!